# Entanglement entropy of a projector

Tags: entanglement, stabilizer-code, linear-algebra, projection-operator

In [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.97.125101) the author goes from the equation (13):  $\rho_A = \frac{|G_A|}{2^{N_A}}\mathcal{P}^{(\overrightarrow k_A)}$, where $\mathcal{P}^{(\overrightarrow k_A)}$ is a projector acting on a subspace $A$, to equation (14) $S_A = N_A - \log_2 |G_A| $ with comment "Since Eq. (13) expresses $ρ_A$ as a projector, its entanglement entropy follows straightforwardly (to eq(14))."

However, to me, it is not straightforward how the fact that $\rho_A$ is a projector results that equation to express entanglement entropy. So my question is: How the fact that $\rho_A$ is a projector simplifies the equation $S_A = -\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_A \log_2 \rho_A)$ into $S_A = N_A - \log_2 |G_A|$?

The paper is about entanglement entropy of the stabilizers but for the purpose of my question, it seems like properties of projector is a main concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is a projector, it must have eigenvalues 0,1. Moreover, since $\text{Tr}(\rho_A)=1$, we know that the rank of $P$ must be $2^{N_A}/|G_A|$.

Now, $S_A=-\text{Tr}(\rho_A\log_2\rho_A)=-\sum\lambda\log_2\lambda$, where $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues. $0\log_20=0$. So, the sum is just
$$
S_A=-\frac{2^{N_A}}{|G_A|}\times\frac{|G_A|}{2^N_A}\log_2\frac{|G_A|}{2^N_A}=-\frac{|G_A|}{2^N_A}=N_A-\log_2|G_A|.
$$

Comment: So... does it go like $\sum_i ^{2^{N_A}/|G_A|} \lambda \log_2 \lambda $? Then how does $\lambda = |G_A|/2^{N_A} $? Isn't it 1?

Comment: No. The eigenvalues of the projector are 1, but the eigenvalues of the density matrix have the prefactor $|G_A|/2^{N_A}$ as well (all the eigenvalues sum to 1).